# My app is work in my emulator but on real device the error Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" is appear

Tags: android, deployment, floating-point, navigation

my app is run in emulator good but when i try it with real device the error appear and the app is stopped please can any one help me 
I think the problem is with api but I don't know helpppp pleaseeee its emergency I should submit the app today

this the error when I did debug when I run the app in device with api 19

> ```
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2/com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #199: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #199: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:627)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                   at com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:188)
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:601)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                   at com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:188) 
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080095
>                   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2327)
>                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.isColorInt(AppCompatResources.java:163)
>                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.inflateColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:110)
>                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:76)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:171)
>                   at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:148)
>                   at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:601) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                   at com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:188) 
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

My main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/wblue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="إجمالي الصرف"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.636"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="إجمالي الرصيد"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="UnknownId" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/gree"
    android:entries="@array/days"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.898"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.004" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    android:layout_width="74dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="420dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="417dp"
        android:layout_height="223dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="754dp"
            android:scrollbarSize="20dp">

        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/Rec"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="306dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.114" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Balance"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.059"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="outflow"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.441"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/wblue"
    app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/wblue"
    app:fab_labelStyle="@style/customFab"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.934"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58000004">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_action1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/gree"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/wblue"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="إضافة حساب بنكي" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_action2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/gree"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/wblue"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="إضافة مصروف شهري" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_action3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/gree"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/wblue"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="إضافة تصنيف جديد" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_action4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/gree"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/wblue"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="إضافة دين" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_action5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/gree"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/wblue"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="إضافة ميزانية" />


</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

project gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  android {
compileSdkVersion 28
//noinspection GradleDependency
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
defaultConfig {


    applicationId "com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
 layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 
'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.philJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'



implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image- 
loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'


implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'


 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you show your project's build.gradle file?

Comment: Because in real world, the phone you are using is not the android & its a useless chinese modified ROM like OxygenOs, ColorOs, FunTouchOs, MIUI,.....

Comment: @DPrince thank you I add it

Comment: @sandhyasasane I tried in many devices all the device I tried is same

Comment: @noraKhaled, Advice is do not test whole project on phones in real world, first make a sample & Android studio provided basic sample project and then try creating classes & copy your ready made codes within that working project